# CSS positioning problem. What did I do wrong?

Tags: css, css-position

My images don't collapse even I set position property.
I'm watching a ["card game" video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bj6lC93JMi0&t=187s) (linked with time) and trying to copy it to follow the same code.
Even though I follow step by step, I have a problem with "positions". I've set `position: absolute;` on my second image but it does not work.

```css
:root {
  --card-width: 157px;
  --card-height: 220px;
}

.card-container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  height: var(--card-height);
  width: var(--card-width);
  perspective: 1000px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
}

.card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card-front,
.card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* .img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;  
  position: relative; ( AFTER I WROTE THIS PART THEY COLLAPSED)
  top: -230px;
  transform: rotateY("180deg");
} */     

.card-img {
  height: 100%;
}

.card-back {
  transform: rotateY("180deg");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="cardGame.js"></script>
    <header>
      <div class="header-title-container">
        <h1>Hunt the Ace of Spades</h1>
      </div>
    </header>

    <main>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-inner">
            <div class="card-front">
              <img src="./images/card-JackClubs.png" alt="" class="card-img" />
              <div class="card-back">
                <img  class="img"  src="./images/card-back-Blue.png" alt="" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not a fix but please note HTML tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

```css
:root {
  --card-width: 157px;
  --card-height: 220px;
}

.card-container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  height: var(--card-height);
  width: var(--card-width);
  perspective: 1000px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
}

.card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card-front,
.card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* .img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;  
  position: relative;                     ( AFTER I WRITE THIS PART THEY COLLAPSED)
  top: -230px;
  transform: rotateY("180deg");
} */     

.card-img {
  height: 100%;
}

.card-back {
  transform: rotateY("180deg");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="cardGame.js"></script>
    <header>
      <div class="header-title-container">
        <h1>Hunt the Ace of Spades</h1>
      </div>
    </header>

    <main>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-inner">
            <div class="card-front">
              <img src="./images/card-JackClubs.png" alt="" class="card-img" />

             </div>
            
  <div class="card-back">
                <img  class="img"  src="./images/card-back-Blue.png" alt="" />
            
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```